# jQuery: Select all elements that are not descendant of a certain class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="container" id = "0" >
   <div class="x" id = "1"> 
      <div id = "2"> 
        <p id = "3">
          <span id = "4" >text</span> 
        </p>
      <div>
    </div>

    <div id="5">
      <div id="6"> 
        <p id="7">
          <span class="x" id="8" >text</span> 
          <span id="9">text</span> 
        </p>
      <div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Can you help me to select all the elements :

- that are descendant of  '.container"'
- not descendant of '.x'
- doesn't have the class '.x' itself.

---

Looking at the HTML above; it should select the elements **5,6,7 and 9**

- Element 1 has class "X"
- Elements 2 is direct child of an element-with-class"X"(Element 1)
- Elements 3 and 4 are descendants an element-with-class"X"(Element 1)

Element 8 has class "X"

---

I have this selector but it keeps selecting the descendants (deep children) of element with class "X"

```
var elements = $('.container').find().parents(':not(.X)').andSelf().filter(':not(.X)');
```

Answer (score 15):

This should do it:

```
$('.container').find(':not(.x):not(.x *)');
```

*Edit:* Reverted to first revision again. I thought it did not work this way, but you have an error in your HTML which makes `#1` parent of all elements, so none is selected.

```
<div class="container" id = "0" >
    <div class="x" id = "1"> 
      <div id = "2"> 
        <p id = "3">
          <span id = "4" >text</span> 
        </p>
      <div> <!-- <-- must be a closing div tag -->
    </div>

    <div id="5">
      <div id="6"> 
        <p id="7">
          <span class="x" id="8" >text</span> 
          <span id="9">text</span> 
        </p>
      <div> <!-- <-- must be a closing div tag -->
    </div>
<div> <!-- <-- must be a closing div tag -->
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$('.container :not(.x):not(.x *)')` be better ?

Comment: Yep. Don't know what I thought back then. Maybe because the OP already used .find.

Answer (score 1):

using wildcards either

```
$(".container :not(* .x)")
```

or

```
$(":not(* .x)", ".container")
```

may work.